# Jira Rest API - Problems to set custom fields

Tags: jira-rest-api

I try to set the field for Testcases in a Testplan. The value I get when reading it is JSONArray.
But when I write the very same JSONArray I extract to a new created Testplan, I get an error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.CannotTransformValueException: Any of available transformers was able to transform given value. Value is: org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray: ["SBNDTST-361","SBNDTST-360","SBNDTST-358","SBNDTST-359"]
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.ValueTransformerManager.apply(ValueTransformerManager.java:83)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.input.IssueInputBuilder.setFieldValue(IssueInputBuilder.java:134)
```

My method to set the field is this:

```
public void updateIssue(String issueKey, String fieldId, Object fieldValue) {
    IssueInput input = new IssueInputBuilder()
            .setFieldValue(fieldId, fieldValue)
            .build();
    restClient.getIssueClient()
            .updateIssue(issueKey, input)
            .claim();
```

The value for the fieldId is "customfield_17473". There is very little documentation on this. Does anyone have an idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by trial and error.
When I send an ArrayList it works.